# Firebase Cloud Function onWrite child value

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase Cloud Function to send FCM upon Real-Time Database Triggered event. How can I get the value of a child ('uid') inside of {followerUid}?

```
exports.sendFollowerNotification = functions.database.ref('/followers/{followedUid}/{followerUid}').onWrite(event => {
  const followerUid = event.params.followerUid;
  const followedUid = event.params.followedUid;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do but will take a stab.

If you are looking to access the data of `uid` inside the node that triggered the function:

```
var uid = event.data.child("uid").val;
```

Have a look at [the documentation on handling event data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#handle_event_data).

Answer (score 3):

I know exactly what you are looking for...

```
var uid = event.data.val();
var uid1 = String(uid);
```

add this uid1 to title or body

```
const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: paypes
        body:  uid1
      }
    };
```

Comment: i got event.data.val() as dictionary . 
in this case how can I parse ?? mean i got multiple childs under that.

Answer (score 1):

Due to recent change in the API.
Following give the data value.

```
event.before.val();
```

or

```
event.after.val();
```

As onWrite(), which triggers when data is created, updated, or deleted in the Realtime Database.
So it gives both before and after value.